# MySQL: find out whether weekday of date is between two weekdays with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, weekday

I have this vb.NET code and would like to write a function in MySQL that does the same thing.

```
Public Function IsWeekdayTimeInRange(DateToCheck As DateTime, StartDayOfWeek As DayOfWeek,
                                                              EndDayOfWeek As DayOfWeek) As Boolean

    Dim WeekdaysInRange As New List(Of DayOfWeek)
    WeekdaysInRange.Add(StartDayOfWeek)
    Dim i As Integer = StartDayOfWeek
    While i <> EndDayOfWeek
        i += 1
        i = If(i = 7, 0, i)
        WeekdaysInRange.Add(i)
    End While

    Return WeekdaysInRange.Contains(DateToCheck.DayOfWeek)
End Function
```

In MySQL I'm currently at this point but since I've never written a SQL function I need some help with this.

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION IS_BETWEEN_WEEKDAYS(d DATETIME, s INT, e INT)
RETURNS BOOLEAN DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE weekdayToCheck INT;
    DECLARE result BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE i INT;
    SET result = false;
    SET weekdayToCheck = WEEKDAY(d);
    SET i = s;
    WHILE(i <> e) DO

        /* more logic here */

    END WHILE;

    RETURN result;
END; |

DELIMITER ;
```

Edit: Since I now learnt that MySQL has `Weekday(Monday) = 0` my functions also require conversion to `Weekday(Sunday) = 0` because my data use that format.

Comment: `weekdayToCheck > s && weekdayToCheck < e` should be a good start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works now. It probably can be more concise but it helped me to think it through.

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION IS_BETWEEN_WEEKDAYS(d DATETIME, s INT, e INT, FirstDayOfWeekIsSunday BOOLEAN)
RETURNS BOOLEAN DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE weekdayToCheck INT;
    DECLARE result BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE i INT;
    SET result = false;
    SET weekdayToCheck = WEEKDAY(d);
    SET i = s;

    IF FirstDayOfWeekIsSunday = TRUE THEN
        SET weekdayToCheck = weekdayToCheck + 1;
        IF weekdayToCheck = 7 THEN
            SET weekdayToCheck = 0;
        END IF;
    END IF;

    IF weekdayToCheck = s THEN
        SET result = true;
    END IF;

    WHILE(i <> e) DO

        SET i = i + 1;

        IF i = 7 THEN
            SET i = 0;
        END IF;

        IF weekdayToCheck = i THEN 
            SET result = true;
        END IF;

    END WHILE;

    RETURN result;
END; |

DELIMITER ;
```

Edit: fixed a problem with the order in the loop. Also added option to function to process `s` and `e` should they assume the week starts with Sunday.
Edit: tested the above and it works. Also create a function that can check whether for example a DateTime is in between Tuesday, 3pm and Thursday, 2am.

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION IS_BETWEEN_WEEKDAYS_AND_TIME(d DATETIME, s INT, starttime TIME, e INT, endtime TIME, FirstDayOfWeekIsSunday BOOLEAN)
RETURNS BOOLEAN DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE weekdayToCheck INT;
    DECLARE result BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE dTime TIME;
    SET result = false;
    SET weekdayToCheck = WEEKDAY(d);
    SET i = s;
    SET dTime = DATE_FORMAT(d, '%H:%i:%s');

    IF FirstDayOfWeekIsSunday = TRUE THEN
        SET weekdayToCheck = weekdayToCheck + 1;
        IF weekdayToCheck = 7 THEN
            SET weekdayToCheck = 0;
        END IF;
    END IF;

    IF weekdayToCheck = s THEN 
        IF ((weekdayToCheck = s AND dTime > starttime) OR (weekdayToCheck = e AND dTime < endtime) OR (weekdayToCheck <> s AND weekdayToCheck <> e)) THEN
            SET result = true;
        END IF;
    END IF;

    WHILE(i <> e) DO

        SET i = i + 1;

        IF i = 7 THEN
            SET i = 0;
        END IF;

        IF weekdayToCheck = i THEN 
            IF ((weekdayToCheck = s AND dTime > starttime) OR (weekdayToCheck = e AND dTime < endtime) OR (weekdayToCheck <> s AND weekdayToCheck <> e)) THEN
                SET result = true;
            END IF;
        END IF;

    END WHILE;

    RETURN result;
END; |

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your definition of "between" is but here I used larger than and smaller than

```
CREATE FUNCTION IS_BETWEEN_WEEKDAYS(d DATETIME, s INT, e INT)
RETURNS BOOLEAN DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE weekdayToCheck INT;
    DECLARE result INT;
    SET weekdayToCheck = WEEKDAY(d);
    SET result = 0;

    IF (s < e) THEN 
       IF  (weekdayToCheck > s AND weekdayToCheck < e) THEN SET result = 1;
       END IF;
    END IF;

    IF (s > e) THEN
       IF (weekdayToCheck > s OR weekdayToCheck < e) THEN SET result = 1;
       END IF;        
    END IF;

    RETURN result; 
END;
```

Perhaps all the if/else clause can be shortened somewhat.

Comment: it's not quite as simple: sunday is 0, saturday 6. If you want to test whether your day is during a weekend this won't work.

Comment: @penCsharpener No, in MySql 0 (zero) is Monday so this should work fine, [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday). Of course, if you want to have a different definition then you need to adjust the code.

Comment: yes, will have to since some values I have to check are saved in the .NET sequence. This makes it even more complex.
However the problem still persists:
ie. check whether Monday is between Saturday and Tuesday:
`0 > 5 && 0 < 1` = false

Comment: @penCsharpener, yes of course. Sorry about that, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Considering a week starts from Monday. Hope this helps:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION IS_BETWEEN_WEEKDAYS(d DATETIME, s INT, e INT)
RETURNS BOOLEAN DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE weekdayToCheck INT;
  DECLARE result TINYINT(1);
  SET weekdayToCheck =  WEEKDAY(d);
  SET result = 0;
  IF(weekdayToCheck > s AND weekdayToCheck < e) THEN
    SET result = 1;
  ELSEIF (s > e AND weekdayToCheck < s AND weekdayToCheck < e) THEN
    SET result = 1;
  END IF;

RETURN result;
END; |

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: thanks, but same problem as with Joakims answer. See my comment there. There is no way around the while loop.

Comment: sorry, this isn't working. I've tested all answers given here with sufficient test data. Thanks anyway. 
By the way what is the `-1` doing in `SET weekdayToCheck = DAYOFWEEK(d) - 1;`

Comment: In which scenario does it fail ?   "-1", so that day 1 starts from Monday.  DAYOFWEEK starts from [ sun(1) - sat(7) ]. You can change it accordingly.

Comment: `-1` is not solving the problem of the week starting with Sunday. Firstly, you have to add 1, secondly even in MySQL the sequence starts with 0 and never ends with 7, but which means if you end up with 7 (or in your case -1) you have to convert that (see my answer). 
In my test query I had one column for each function and yours always returned `0`.

Comment: eg: For tadays date [select DAYOFWEEK('2018-07-17');] returns the value 3. Since today is the second day of the week, we will subtract 1. Please give me a date and day of week where this function is failing.

Comment: Pardon me; you are using a different function for getting the numerical weekday altogether. Only noticed after I run your last select myself. That makes sense then.  But why not just use WEEKDAY() since then you can save the -1... 
However, as edited in my question `s` and `e` assume Sunday as `0`. 
Anyhow, create a table with all the days of a month and run your function on it. It's still not working for me. Only returns false.

Comment: No problem. Consider today's date which is 2nd day of the week. IS_BETWEEN_WEEKDAYS("2018-07-17", 1, 3) will return 1,  IS_BETWEEN_WEEKDAYS("2018-07-17", 4, 3) will return 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176216/discussion-between-pencsharpener-and-sahal).